# I have include wp-config, should I add global $wpdb also?

Tags: database, wordpress

Usually, In my wordpress website, when I modify template page file, it is done by only add global $wpdb for databse operation without including wp-config file.

Now, I create my own php file in public_html folder for database operation. For this to work, I should include wp-config.php file.

My question is should I add global $wpdb if I have already include wp-config.php file?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. if you include `wp-load.php` those will load `load.php` what is includes function below.

If you load `wp-config` that will load `wp-settings` what is already load `load.php` both is using `require_once()` for `load.php`

```
function require_wp_db() {
    global $wpdb;

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/wp-db.php' );
    if ( file_exists( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' ) )
        require_once( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/db.php' );

    if ( isset( $wpdb ) )
        return;

    $wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST );
}
```

Comment: Hello @lolka_bolka thanks for your fast answer. This is the answer that I'm looking for. If you don't mind, I have second question related to this one: What if it is a plugin global variable, should I add global $pluginglobalvariablename? Does $pluginglobalvariablename included in wp-config like $wpdb? thx

Comment: I've never met with this `$pluginglobalvariablename` variable. Maybe it is a variable what you want to use globally from a plugin?

Comment: yes it's a variable of a plugin that someone created it. when I modify template page file I need to write global $variablename for this to work. Again, as this is a plugin variable, should I write global $variablename in my own php file in public_html folder or not for this plugin variable to work?

Comment: usually never write into someone else plugin, because if you do, and plugin refresh, your changes will lost. Contact with the owner of the plugin, or write a hook on it, read the documentation of the plugin the achive what you want. Ask it into another question with the details.